# Woocommerce pagination problem

Tags: plugins

I'm working on project that needs to have WooCommerce implemented, and there is a list of products on main page, using a original theme loop. I managed to display all posts and it's data, and now I'm encountering problems with themes pagination. It's working kinda fine - it recognises the number of items (products), calculates number of pages, and works fine for first 3 pages.

Then I found out that I have enough posts (normal blog posts, not Woo products) so the pagination is working fine for first 3 pages - which is number where normal blog post pagination would stop.

How can I fix this, so pagination goes for example to page 5, and not show me 404 error page?

Here's the loop:

```
<?php 
                $args = array(
                    'posts_per_page' => '4',
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
                );
                $homepage_query = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>
            <?php //query_posts('posts_per_page=4&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>  
                <?php while ( $homepage_query->have_posts() ) : $homepage_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if($style == 'blog_style') { ?>
                    <div id="blog-style" class="post-box">

                        <?php get_template_part('content', 'blog'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="post-box proizvod-box grid_4 <?php aero_post_box_class(); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                        <?php //get_template_part('content', ''); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And here's the pagenavi function file:
http://jsbin.com/umumeq/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Try `$homepage_query->have_posts()` instead of `have_posts()` in your `if` condition.

Comment: No, same thing as before. But thanks for this!

Comment: Your pagenavi code is a nightmare! It's intermingling both `$homepage_query` and the main query, so no wonder there's conflict - you'd be much better off hooking onto (& overriding) the main query with the `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts` hook.

Comment: Can you please post a short example? Would mean a lot!

Comment: That code was written when only blog posts were being displayed, and worked great. But now, problem - as you can see.